# Javascript onclick function being called on page load

Tags: javascript, function, events, onclick, onload

I have a simple Javascript function to be called when a button on the page is clicked. But it is getting called as soon as the page loads. Can anyone please tell me what the problem here is?

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">ClicMe!</button>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

While the 'script.js' file is as follows.

```
var url = "example.txt";

function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xhttp) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = loadDoc(url, myFunction);
```

Comment: you are calling the function here `btn.onclick = loadDoc(url, myFunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your script is calling the function instead of assigning the handler to it. Since you have arguments that you want to call it with, you need to use something to bundle the arguments and function together for when it is called. If you replace the last line with the following, it should work:

```js
btn.onclick = loadDoc.bind(undefined, url, myFunction) // "this" value is not needed, so it is left undefined
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is very compact and it worked. I had earlier just found out the problem but I had solved it by calling loadDoc with parameters from another function and then assigning that function to onclick, but yours is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must attach an event listener that invoke the function when a user clicks a button:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  loadDoc(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly calling `loadDoc()` function in your JS file.
You should try this -

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick='loadDoc()'>ClicMe!</button>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an arrow function like this:

```
btn.onclick = () => loadDoc(url, myFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had used the same method as yours but not compacted it in an arrow function, rather a separate function. Your is more compact, in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick='loadDoc()'>ClicMe!</button>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```